# Specific PHP Mysql query not working in root folder

Tags: php, mysql, apache

A bit of history first. We moved a site from one hosting provider(hostexcellence) to another (1and1) because the client wanted to get their own hosting seperate from our reseller hosting.

The site is working fine except for one thing.

For some reason or another specific queries that are done in the root folder are not working, but work perfectly fine in a subfolder. Also to note on top of that, if I do a query which should return multiple results it works fine, but if I do a query that should return a single line item it returns an empty set.

Here is one of the queries

```
'SELECT `specials`.*, DATE_FORMAT(startdate, "%d %b %Y") AS sdate, DATE_FORMAT(enddate, "%d %b %Y") AS edate FROM `specials` WHERE enddate > NOW() and active = 1'
```

But then if I run a similar query on a different table it works fine

```
'SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(startdate, "%d %b %Y") AS sdate, DATE_FORMAT(enddate, "%d %b %Y") AS edate FROM events WHERE enddate >= NOW() AND active = 1'
```

As I mentioned above, these do not work in the root folder of the website but work in any subfolder.

mysql_error() does not return anything. It just returns an empty result.

Any ideas, as I have been trying to trace the error for the past two days.

It is running on  an apache server if that makes any difference, and there is no htaccess file in that directory at the moment.

Thanks in advance

***edit***

I tried all of the methods mentioned below, and I retried the queries separate from that page they work fine on other pages and in phpmyadmin. So I am slightly at wits end.

Comment: `open_basedir` PHP config option?

Comment: It's hard to believe that SQL code is directory-aware. Most likely, you haven't enabled PHP error logging or your error reporting level is to low.

Comment: I have added the following to the page(as the options that the hosting provider allows in the php.ini is pretty limited) to test it out but it does not return any errors:
`ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__) . '/error_log.txt');
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this-

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(startdate, "%d %b %Y") AS sdate, DATE_FORMAT(enddate, "%d %b %Y") AS edate FROM specials WHERE enddate > NOW() and active = 1'
```

Also, as a backup plan, check your connection to the DB and try to return errors both from the connection command and the mysql_select_db
(or whichever method you use to choose your Database).

Comment: OK, I have tried the string, but it does not make a difference, and the connection is open as I am able to run successful  queries on other tables before I query that specific table

Comment: What IDE/Editor are you writting your code? In what manner are the tables queried related to eachother?

Comment: I use textmate to edit my files and upload via ftp. It is simple autoincrement fields. But in the query on top in question I am not searching by ID, but rather by the date and if the active flag is set on one specific table.